# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatexception

```
    private void ReadUnitPrice()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the unit gross price: ");
        unitPrice = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

This should work, but I'm missing something obvious. Whenever I input a double it gives me the error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
Note that 'unitPrice' is declared as a double.

Comment: What values are you inputting?

Comment: values within 0-10 like 4.5 or 5.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that you're using wrong comma separation symbol or even made an other error whilst specifying double value.
Anyway in such cases you must use [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3s27fasw.aspx) method which is safe in terms of exception and allows specify format provider, basically culture to be used.

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    out double result
)
```

> The TryParse method is like the Parse(String, NumberStyles,
>   IFormatProvider) method, except this method does not throw an
>   exception if the conversion fails. If the conversion succeeds, the
>   return value is true and the result parameter is set to the outcome of
>   the conversion. If the conversion fails, the return value is false and
>   the result parameter is set to zero.

EDIT: Answer to comment

```
if(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out unitPrice))
{
    // parse error
}else
{
   // all is ok, unitPrice contains valid double value
}
```

Also you can try:

```
double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), 
                NumberStyle.Float, 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                out unitPrice))
```

Comment: yep, I just tried that actually.. and guess what, it works. I hate the swedish comma separation symbol now..

Comment: TryParse takes in more parametres in its argument and since I'm a newbie in C# and not quite familiar with where TryParse then sends the result (since it returns a bool) I'll stick with Parse for now. "Receiving 2 return values" seems a bit over my head atm but I'll keep TryParse in mind for future use. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryuji89 : see updted answer, EDIT part