# C# Converting string to int fails

Tags: c#, mysql, type-conversion

I am working on a little project, that at a certain point need to convert a `string` to `int`.

I tried the following things:

```
//first try
value1 = int.TryParse(value[0].tostring(), out i)

//second
value1 = Convert.ToInt32(value[0].tostring())

//third
value1 = int.Parse(value[0].tostring())
```

I even wrote my own conversion method because I was at a loss.

The values I am trying to convert are queried from a `MySQL` database.

Thank for your help

EDIT:

I know tryparse should have 2 params.

And the error iam getting is a formatexception
Input string was not in a correct format.

I got that on all the tries.

the value in my test case is 2500
Keep in mind that that number is received from a db
I tried the above snippets while using a hard coded value. And that works fine.

EDIT 2: 
[image: the values]
//[http://imgur.com/NSyg2rJ](https://imgur.com/NSyg2rJ)

Comment: What is the declaration for `value`? What is the contents of `value[0]`?

Comment: its `ToString`, not `tostring`, also `int.TryParse` takes two arguments.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: int.TryParse(value[0].tostring()) should have two parameters http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse

Comment: Can you give more details on what the value for `value[0].ToString()` is?  It might be a string that cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: @kami The value is 2500

Comment: @user214623 The code appears solid, the value is probably not what you are expecting and/or it has a character that cannot be displayed.  Use `Debug.WriteLine` to output the text or use a debugger to see it's exact value at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One:**
The signature of `int.TryParse()` is incorrect:

```
int result = 0;
bool parsedSuccessfully = Int32.TryParse(value[0].ToString(), out result);
//If successful, result will hold the value.
```

**Two:**
The signature of `Convert.ToInt32()` is correct, minus the case of the `.ToString()` method. This is failing because `value` or `value[0]` is `null`, or it cannot convert something like the `string` `"NotAnInt"` to an `int`.

**Three:**
The signature of `int.Parse()` is correct, but is failing for the same reasons as two.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. i typoed the tryparse method. of cousre there should be 2 params. 

As for the value in values[0] that is 2500, so that shouldn't be a problem. Right?

Comment: If values[0] is 2500 it should work. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Nope it doesnt... I know it weird...

Comment: Iam lossing my mind over this

Comment: What is the exact type and value of values[0]? I assume 2500 is the value. Are you sure there are no illegal characters in the input string that could make it fail? Try [specifying the format provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532801/system-formatexception-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format) and see if that still fails.

Comment: oh wauw, i just printed the string length...
2500 should have a string length of 4...
The string was length 5

Comment: so how can i see the "missing" char

Comment: Try using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11138139/1229237) on your input string. I'm a little out of my depth now, but I believe you can have non-printable characters in your string. This could be preventing the conversion. But it's only a guess.

Comment: Stupid me there is an euro sign in the string. it is received from db. which is a latin db so maybe that changes things

Comment: Well there's your problem. However, [you can convert with the currency symbol in the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094334/format-currency-string-to-integer).

Comment: the problem is of course that the symbol is not visible when debugging and i tried the method you gave me. but it still doesnt work

Comment: please check the images included on my post that is what it looks like

Comment: Did you remove the symbol from the string? If you did then I am out of ideas...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed it by removing the euro sign in the database

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
int value1;
if (Int.TryParse(value[0].ToString(), out value1))
{
    //conversion successful
}
```